# My list objects are being destroyed

Tags: c++, list, function, pointers

```
 list<Book> *books = new list<Book>;

    list<Book>::iterator pos;

   void Administrator::addBook()
    {
        Book *newBook = new Book();
        cout << "Would you like to enter a book?" << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        cout << endl;

        if (userInput == "yes")
        {

            cout << "What is the title of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> title;

            cout << "What is the author of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> author;

            cout << "What is the ISBN of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> ISBN;

            cout << endl;

            newBook->setTitle(title);
            newBook->setAuthor(author);
            newBook->setISBN(ISBN);
            newBook->setAvailability(true);

            books->push_back(*newBook);

        }
    }

*****************
```

I really need help with this, i have received a few answers today but none have helped me with this problem. This is my `admin` class. It creates books on the heap and stores them in an `stl::list`

```
void Guest::searchBook(Book* search)
{
    string searchBook;
    cout << "What book would you like to search for?" << endl;
    cin >> searchBook;

    printBookDetails();
}
```

---

This is my `Guest` class, what i would like to do here is to search through the list of books i created in my `Administrator` class but when it goes into the function `printBookDetails`, my list contains no elements, im assuming they've been destroyed.

```
Administrator* admin1 = new Administrator("jayfitz91", 24681357);
Guest* guest1 = new Guest("guest", 0000);

void main()
{

    //Everything here works fine
    admin1->addBook();
    admin1->addBook();
    admin1->makeAvailable();
    admin1->printBookDetails();

   //My list is destroyed at this point and it returns nothing
    guest1->printBookDetails();
```

My `Guest` class inherits the `printBookDetails` from my `Administrator` class

All of the admin functions work but as soon as it gets to guest, the elements disappear.

Is there anyway i can get around this? The help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: This is not clear.  You don't show how admin1 and guest1 get created, or the class declarations.

Comment: Theres already a good bit of code there, i just didnt want to throw everything down. I just create them in the main, ill edit it now

Comment: guest1 is a separate object, and has no relation to admin1 object.  Why do you think a list in admin1 should be available to guest1?

Comment: To be honest i'm still only learning, this is my first big project. I wasn't sure that was the case. So is there no way for me to gain access to that list from the guest class?

Comment: So add a method to return the list from the Admin class and pass that is as a parameter to the guest.printBookDetails method.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, thanks for that, its only printing out one element at the moment but im sure ill figure it out, thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OldProgrammer, i realised i had to return the list of books from my `Admin` class and pass it through as a parameter to my `printBookDetails` method in my guest class:

```
//Admin class
//Now returning a list
list<Book> Administrator::addBook()
{
    Book *newBook = new Book();
    cout << "Would you like to enter a book?" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;

    if (userInput == "yes")
    {

        cout << "What is the title of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> title;

        cout << "What is the author of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> author;

        cout << "What is the ISBN of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> ISBN;

        cout << endl;

        newBook->setTitle(title);
        newBook->setAuthor(author);
        newBook->setISBN(ISBN);
        newBook->setAvailability(true);

        books->push_back(*newBook);

    }
    return *books;
}



 //Guest class function

void Guest::printBookList(list<Book> *tempList)
{
    pos = tempList->begin();
    for (pos = tempList->begin(); pos != tempList->end(); ++pos)
    {
        cout << pos->getTitle() << "\n"
            << pos->getAuthor() << "\n"
            << pos->getISBN() << "\n"
            << pos->getAvailability() << "\n"
            << "******************************" << endl;

    }

}

//Main class function

    //Create a temporary variable for the list
    list<Book> tempList;

    //pass it through to the method
    guest1->printBookList(&tempList);
```

Comment: A better way to do this is to pass in the list by const reference, that way Guest is prevented from modifying the list (unless you want it modified)

Answer (score -1):

First off, you don't have to dynamically create your list object.

```
list<Book> books = new list<Book>();
```

You do this because

1. you have less responsibility: you don't have to release the resources contained by books. It will automatically be released.
2. list is a stl container, which means it automatically handles dynamic allocations.

This is different if you use an dynamically allocated array...

---

I think your list is "gone" is because Guest and Administrator has two entirely different list.

To solve this issue, you should grant access to the book list that Administrator has to your Guest.

Or extract out the book list and store it in another class that allow access to the list to both Administrator and Guest.